# Grouping a range using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of objects (ID,Price,SalesID )
How can I group this list based on a range of Price values?

Say from 0-10,10-20,>20

I want ouput as a list of groups

```
0-9 -> object1,object2  
10-20 -> object3,object5,object7
>20   -> object8,object10,object11..
```

Comment: In what context? LINQ in memory or LINQ to some SQL provider?

Comment: The question is slightly inconsistent since you have price 10 in two groups.  If you can define your groups more clearly, I think @StevieB's solution would do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make groups that contain the range names:

```
var result = prices.GroupBy(x => x.Price < 10 ? "0-10" 
                                              : x.Price < 20 ? "10-20" : ">20")
                   .Select(g => new { g.Key, g }
```

(assuming that < 0 does not exist)

Comment: x.Price < 20 will also cover cases where x.Price < 10. Maybe reorder the conditions.

Answer (score 3):

This will group them in ranges of >20, 10-20, <10 (i.e. 0-9 as price can't be less than 0 I assume).

```
objects.GroupBy(x => x.Price > 20 ? 2 : x.Price >= 10 ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: I think this is not what Robert_Junior intended. He's looking for very specific ranges (0-10, 10-20, > 20).

Comment: @MauroCerutti exactly

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
objects.GroupBy(o=>o.Price>=20?2:(int)(o.Price/10))
```

Comment: this will group them into only two gropus, one "in range" and other - "not in range". The question was different

Comment: right you are. actually, it will then depend on how the windows are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Define an `enum` to represent you ranges:

```
public enum PriceRange {
   LessThanTen,
   TenToTwenty,
   MoreThanTwenty
}
```

Then define a method similar to the following somewhere:

```
private static PriceRange ExtractRange(MyClass o) {
    if (o.Price < 10)
        return PriceRange.LessThanTen;
    else if (o.Price <= 20)
        return PriceRange.TenToTwenty;
    else
        return PriceRange.MoreThanTwenty;
}
```

the you can do something like:

```
var groups = myObjects.GroupBy(m => ExtractRange(m));
```

You can output like this:

```
foreach( var g in grp ) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", g.Key, string.Join(",", g.Select(o => o.ToString())));
    }
```

Assuming that you objects' `ToString()` outputs something useful to you.